# how to add columns automatically when clicking a button using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to automatically create more columns when am clicking a button.

I have an addmember button. When am clicking that button, the text boxes for name of the member, fathers name, mother name and DOB should be created.

Can anyone help me in doing this.

#### EDIT

I need to keep the column name as such and add text boxes.

#### EDIT

Columns should be added and not rows. That too only text fields should be added.

#### EDIT

Can anyone help me in finding the solution.

This is what i want::

Add Memeber- Button

Name of group member     textbox11    textbox12   textbox13
Father name              textbox21    textbox22   textbox23
Mother name              textbox31    textbox32   textbox33 
DOB                      textbox41    textbox42   textbox43

First and second column should remain there evrytime.

When i click the "add member" button for the first time the textbox12, textbox22, textbox32, textbox42 should appear. And when clicked for the second time textbox13, textbox23, textbox33 and textbox43 should also appear.

Please can anyone help me in solving this.

Thanks in advance,
Amith

#### EDIT

Can anyone help me in solving this problem. Please.....

Comment: You should really avoid using the `FONT` tag, use `SPAN` instead.

Comment: Are you using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) or just plain JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

Append new rows dynamically using Javascript.

```
<script>
    function addMember() {
        var table = document.getElementById("member_table");
        table.innerHTML =  table.innerHTML + "<tr> ... your table fields here ...</tr>"

    }
</script>

<input name="addMember" type="button" name="AddMember" value='Add Member' onclick="addMember()"/>
```

Comment: Seems to work for me. Did you change `... your table fields here ...` in my example to real HTML?

Comment: yes i have added my html code where u mentioned. But it is showing syntax error.
This is the code.

Comment: function addMember() {
        var table = document.getElementById("member_table");
        table.innerHTML =  table.innerHTML + "
 <tr>
        <td align="center" width="10%">08. </td>
        <td width="30%" align="right">Name of the group member : <FONT color="red">*</FONT></td>
 <td width="30%" class="fieldcellwithinputwide" align="left" ><INPUT type="text" /></td>
     </tr>
              
              <tr>
                     <td align="center" width="10%">09. </td>
 "}

Comment: you are using double quotes in HTML you're adding. Javascript interprets first double quote as end of the string, and that causes syntax error. Switch to single quotes in appended HTML, or escape double quotes using backslash.

Comment: I have replaced the double quotes qith single quotes as below. Even then it is not working

function addMember() {
        var table = document.getElementById("member_table");
        table.innerHTML =  table.innerHTML +"
   <tr><td align='center' width='10%'>08. </td>
                     <td width='30%' align='right'>Name of the group member : </td>
      <td width='30%' class='fieldcellwithinputwide' align='left' ><INPUT type='text' /></td>
     </tr>"

}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5307/discussion-between-amith-and-socha23)

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this;

```
<input name="addMember" type="button" name="AddMember" value='Add Member' onclick="addRow('tableID')"/>


function addRow(tableID) { 
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var element1 = document.createElement("font");
            cell1.appendChild(element1);

            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;

            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var element2 = document.createElement("input");
            element2.type = "text";
            cell3.appendChild(element2);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this function:

```
function addMember()
{
    var tblBody = document.getElementById('member_table').tBodies[0];
    var newRow = tblBody.insertRow(-1);
    var newCell0 = newRow.insertCell(0);
    var newInput = document.createElement('input');
    newInput.type = 'text';
    newInput.value = 'mothers name';
    newInput.style.color = 'blue';
    newCell0.appendChild(newInput);
    /* add more options like this ...*/
}
```